# How the color of attributed text inherits the parent color?

Tags: swift, string, nsmutableattributedstring

For example I have to put a String "Hello, world!" in the `UIButton`.

And "Hello," and "world!" should be different colors.

"Hello," has the default color of `UIButton`, and "world!" has the customized color by `NSMutableAttributedString`.

I explain again with code and result.

```
// Using a library `SwiftyAttributes`(https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes)
button.attributedText = "Hello, ".withJust() + "world!".withTextColor(.red)

button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

**I want:** Hello,(black) world!(red)

```
button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
```

**I want:** Hello,(red) world!(red)

```
button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
```

**I want:** Hello,(blue) world!(red)

**But always the result is:** Hello,(black) world!(red)

...

Maybe I think the priority of `NSMutableAttributedString` default color is higher than `UIButton` default color.

But can I see the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to imagine there is some kind of "inheritance" between the title color and the color in the attributed string. There isn't. There is no relationship between them at all.

As soon as you start using `attributedText`, you are *completely* in charge of the colors in the text. The tint color and title color become completely irrelevant. If you want Hello in blue you must *set* it to blue *in the attributed string*.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use `NSMutableAttributedString` for this purpose, but you should built up your `NSMutableAttributedString` instead of doing as you have done. Here is some code for you to get started with:

```
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World")
attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blue, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 5))
attrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 6, length: 5))
button.setAttributedTitle(attrStr, for: .normal)
```

Note that the `location` is where you want to start the coloring and `length` is where you want to stop. So `Hello` becomes `location: 0` and `length: 5`.

**Output:**
[image]